# How to fix PyQt5 GUI freezing

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I've created a simple GUI for my python app with QtDesigner. When i try to run my code it works properly but my problem now is that when i try to run my code using the convert button on my GUI the interface freeze or unresponsive and it will only be responsive after it finishes executing the code. Now my question is how can i fix this?

Heres my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'GUI.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox

import sys
import excel2img
import openpyxl as xl


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(361, 303)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btn_exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 240, 75, 23))
        self.btn_exit.setObjectName("btn_exit")
        self.btn_openfile = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_openfile.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 75, 23))
        self.btn_openfile.setObjectName("btn_openfile")
        self.btn_convert = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_convert.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 75, 23))
        self.btn_convert.setObjectName("btn_convert")
        #self.btn_send = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        #self.btn_send.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 75, 23))
        #self.btn_send.setObjectName("btn_send")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 361, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    #Widgets
        self.btn_openfile.clicked.connect(self.openfile)
        self.btn_exit.clicked.connect(self.exit)
        self.btn_convert.clicked.connect(self.convert)
    #Widgets

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_exit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.btn_openfile.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File"))
        self.btn_convert.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Convert File"))
        #self.btn_send.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send Payroll"))

    #My Functons

    fileName = ''
    @classmethod
    def openfile(cls):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File", "", "Excel files (*.xlsx *xls)")
        cls.fileName = fname[0]

    def exit(self):      
        quit_msg = "Are you sure you want to exit the program?"
        reply = QMessageBox.question(None, 'Prompt', 
                         quit_msg, QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()

    def convert(self):
        wb = xl.load_workbook(self.fileName, read_only=True)
        ws = wb.active
        a, b = 2, 2
        x, y = 1, 44
        z, w = 1, 44

        max_row = ws.max_row
        temp = 0
        loop_num = 0
        while temp < max_row:
            temp += 52
            loop_num += 1

        print(loop_num)

        for i in range(loop_num * 2):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                cell = "Sheet1!A{}:F{}".format(x,y)
                ccell = 'B{}'.format(a)
                var = ws[ccell].value
                a += 52
                x += 52
                y += 52

            else:
                cell = "Sheet1!H{}:M{}".format(z,w)
                ccell = 'I{}'.format(b)
                var = ws[ccell].value       
                b += 52
                z += 52
                w += 52

            name = '{}.png'.format(var)
            excel2img.export_img(self.fileName, name, "", cell )

            print('generating image {}'.format(i + 1))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do not modify the code generated by Qt Designer but create another class that inherits from the appropriate widget and use the initial class to fill it.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>First of all you should not modify the class generated by Qt Designer so before applying my solution you must regenerate the .py so you must use pyuic again:</sub>

```
pyuic5 your_ui.ui -o design.py -x
```

---

onsidering the above, the problem is that you have a time consuming task blocking the eventloop preventing it from doing its jobs like reacting to user events. A possible solution for this is to use threads:

```py
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import excel2img
import openpyxl as xl

from design import Ui_MainWindow


def task(fileName):

    wb = xl.load_workbook(fileName, read_only=True)
    ws = wb.active
    a, b = 2, 2
    x, y = 1, 44
    z, w = 1, 44

    max_row = ws.max_row
    temp = 0
    loop_num = 0
    while temp < max_row:
        temp += 52
        loop_num += 1

    print(loop_num)

    for i in range(loop_num * 2):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            cell = "Sheet1!A{}:F{}".format(x, y)
            ccell = "B{}".format(a)
            var = ws[ccell].value
            a += 52
            x += 52
            y += 52

        else:
            cell = "Sheet1!H{}:M{}".format(z, w)
            ccell = "I{}".format(b)
            var = ws[ccell].value
            b += 52
            z += 52
            w += 52

        name = "{}.png".format(var)
        excel2img.export_img(fileName, name, "", cell)

        print("generating image {}".format(i + 1))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.Ui_MainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Widgets
        self.btn_openfile.clicked.connect(self.openfile)
        self.btn_exit.clicked.connect(self.exit)
        self.btn_convert.clicked.connect(self.convert)

    fileName = ""

    @classmethod
    def openfile(cls):
        cls.fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, "Open File", "", "Excel files (*.xlsx *xls)"
        )

    def exit(self):
        quit_msg = "Are you sure you want to exit the program?"
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
            None,
            "Prompt",
            quit_msg,
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No,
        )

        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()

    def convert(self):
        threading.Thread(target=task, args=(self.fileName,), daemon=True).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents() within your for loop to make the Qt's event loop proceed the incoming event (from keyboard or mouse)

Hope i have helped

Comment: thanks for your answer. Im able to move the GUI a little bit by adding the code you mention but it looks like it's still freezing and i dont want that to happen is there any way around?